# How to get the string after a certain a HTML Dom

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

Here is the html:

```
<td width="551">
<p><strong>Full Time Faculty<br>
<strong></strong>Assistant Professor</strong></p>Doctorate of Business Administration<br><br>
<strong>Phone</strong>: +88 01756567676<br>
<strong>Email</strong>: frank.wade@email.com<br> 
<strong>Office</strong>: NAC739<br>
<br><p><b>Curriculum Vitae</b></p></td>
```

The output I want is:

+88 01756567676

frank.wade@email.com

NAC739

I used simple_html_dom to parse the data.

Here's the code I wrote. It works if the contact info part is wrapped with a paragraph tag. (

)

```
$contact = $facultyData->find('strong[plaintext^=Phone]');
$contact = $contact[0]->parent();
$element = explode("\n", strip_tags($contact->plaintext));

$regex = '/Phone:(.*)/';
if (preg_match($regex, $element[0], $match)) 
    $phone = $match[1];

$regex = '/Email:(.*)/';
if (preg_match($regex, $element[1], $match)) 
    $email = $match[1];

$regex = '/Office:(.*)/';
if (preg_match($regex, $element[2], $match)) 
    $office = $match[1];
```

Is there any way to get those 3 lines by matching with  tag?

Comment: You might want to use `DOMDocument` instead.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use xpath function like

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($DomAsString);
$theText = $xml->xpath('//strong[. ="Phone"]/following-sibling::text()');
```

some snippings to remove the ': ', and of course fixing the dom structure

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to parse this as HTML or deal with DOM tree. You can explode your HTML string into pieces, then remove what is extra in each piece to get what you want:

```
<?php 

$str = <<<str
<td width="551">
<p><strong>Full Time Faculty<br>
<strong></strong>Assistant Professor</strong></p>Doctorate of Business Administration<br><br>
<strong>Phone</strong>: +88 01756567676<br>
<strong>Email</strong>: frank.wade@email.com<br>
<strong>Office</strong>: NAC739<br>
<br><p><b>Curriculum Vitae</b></p></td>
str;

// We explode $str and use '</strong>' as delimiter and get only the part of result that we need
$lines = array_slice(explode('</strong>', $str), 3, 3);
// Define a function to remove extra text from left and right of our so called lines
function stripLine($line) {
    // ltrim ' ;' characters and remove everything after (and including) '<br>'
    return preg_replace('/<br>.*/is', '', ltrim($line, ' :'));
}
$lines = array_map('stripLine', $lines);

print_r($lines);
```

See code output [here](https://3v4l.org/DFm8N).

Answer (score 0):

Or just use straight regex:

```
preg_match('|Phone</strong>: [^<]+|', $str, $m) or die('no phone');
$phone = $m[1];
```